# Upload PDF to mongoDB with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pdf

I'm building a small API and I need to save a PDF file into my database.
Here are my schema and post method so far

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const restaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    menu: {type: String, required: true}, 
    qr: {type: String, required: false} 
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantSchema); 






router.post('/' ,(req, res, next) =>{
const restaurant = new Restaurant({  
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    name: req.body.name,
    menu: req.body.menu,
    qr: req.body.qr
});

restaurant.save().then(result => { 
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Created Restaurant succesfully',
        createdRestaurant: {
            name: result.name,
            menu: result.menu,
            qr: result.qr,
            _id: result._id,
            request:{
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/restaurants/' + result._id
            }
        }
    });
```

What I want to do is to add an additional field on my schema that can handle a pdf document

Comment: You usually don't save static files in a database, you upload them to a static server and save the URL \ path.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks for answering